# Wifi stops working after some time on ubuntu 14.10 and ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, drivers

I tried many solutions from askubuntu.com but non of them work.
Internet stops working after some time. Sometimes it works continuously but sometimes not. Ethernet is working fine all time.
I tested wifi on both Ubuntu 14.10(3.16.0-28-generic) and 14.04.

It's working fine on windows 8.

```
$ lshw -C network

*-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 00
   serial: 38:b1:db:a9:b8:2f
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=3.16.0-28-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.102 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:18 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:e0500000-e0503fff
```

Comment: i don't know why my answer delete which works 100% !. anyway answer is here now https://gist.github.com/AkashkumarDev/034878956fde42191dbf

Answer (score 0):

It might be issue with the power off manager, so please try the below command and check,

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

Comment: thanks for answer. got error:
Error for wireless request "Set Power Management" (8B2C) :
    SET failed on device wlan0 ; Operation not supported.